# Remove first n "words" from string variable in Bash

Tags: string, bash

I want to remove the first 4 words from my string variable "DATES".

Does someone have a simple solution for this?

Here my example:

```
DATES="31 May 2021 10:22:01 30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01"
WC=$(echo $DATES | wc -w)                                                                                          
DATE_COUNT=$(( $WC / 4 - 1 ))                                                                                     

for i in {0..$DATE_COUNT}                                                                                          
do                                                                                                                 
   YEAR=$(echo $DATES | awk '{print $3}')                                                                         
   MONTH=$(echo $DATES | awk '{print $2}')                                                                        
   MONTH=$( date --date="$(printf "01 %s" $MONTH)" +"%m")                                                         
   DAY=$(echo $DATES | awk '{print $1}')                                                                          
   TIME=$(echo $DATES | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/://g')                                                          
   DATE_ARRAY[$i]="$YEAR$MONTH$DAY$TIME"                                                                          
    
   #Remove first 4 words from string                                                                               
done
```

Comment: Huh?? `echo "31 May 2021 10:22:01 30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01" | awk '{ for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++) printf (i>5) ? " %s" : "%s", $i; print ""}'` Result `"30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01"` Or are you talking about some other 4 words and some other string other than `$DATES`?

Comment: No I was talking about $DATES

Comment: @user8514011 :  `for i in {0..$DATE_COUNT}` : This executes the loop exactly once, with `i` set to (i.e., assuming that DATE_COUNT is 2) the string `{0..2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut`.

```sh
DATES="31 May 2021 10:22:01 30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01"
echo $DATES | cut -d' ' -f 5-
```

Output:

```
30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01
```

You can even use it for a cleaner solution than `awk`, like this:

```sh
YEAR=$(echo $DATES | cut -d' ' -f 3)
```

---

**General version to remove n first words**

```sh
remove_n_first_words(){
    echo $2 | cut -d' ' -f $(($1+1))-
}
remove_n_first_words 4 "$DATES"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using bash regex operator `=~`:

```
$ [[ $DATES =~ ^(([^ ]+ +){4})(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `read` ?

```
DATES="31 May 2021 10:22:01 30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01"
read -ra dates <<< "$DATES"; echo "${dates[@]:4}"
```

---

Or just store the data in an array directly.

```
DATES=(31 May 2021 10:22:01 30 May 2021 10:23:01 29 May 2021 10:24:01)

echo "${DATES[@]:4}"
```

To get the total words/elements like with `wc -c`

```
echo "${#DATES[*]}"
```